# PHP json_encode array with foreign characters

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I am retrieving some data from a database and I want to json encode it and store it in a file. My database tables and connection are set to utf8 and if I `print_r` the array of database results I can see the foreign characters at this point are correct, for example the following value: `Tiefes Türkis`

However if I use json_encode and output the generated json the foreign characters have been managled. The value now reads: `Tiefes T\u00fcrkis`

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Believe you should use `json_encode($yourData, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)`

Comment: @davidkonrad that worked thanks so much! Do you want to post an actual answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @david You ***could*** if you'd *like to*… (emphasis that it's an optional preference)

Comment: No, there seem to be plenty of duplicates. @deceze, yes off course :)